# Using $match after a $lookup in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections and I want to get fields from both, so I'm using `$lookup` in an aggregation pipeline.

This works fine and returns all the documents with an extra field, an array with 0 or 1 elements (an object). If 0 elements, it means that the `JOIN`(in SQL world) didn't return anything. If 1 element, it means that there was a match and the element in an object with the fields of the second collection.

Now that I have those results, I'd like to use `$match` in order to filter some of the results.

In order to use `$match` I first want to use `$unwind` on that new extra field in order to extract the array. The problem is once I insert the `$unwind` stage, the result of the query is a single document.

Why is this happening? How can I `$unwind` and then `$match` all the documents I got from the `$lookup` stage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assume we have documents after `lookup`:

```
{doc:{_id:1, lookupArray:[{doc:1},{doc:2}]}}
```

and

```
{doc:{_id:2, lookupArray:[/* empty */]}}
```

when we `$unwind` without any options we will get:

1. {doc:{_id:1, lookupArray:{doc:1}}}
2. {doc:{_id:1, lookupArray:{doc:2}}}
3. null

and when we specify

```
 { $unwind: { path: "$array", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }
```

then we will get:

1. {doc:{_id:1, lookupArray:{doc:1}}}
2. {doc:{_id:1, lookupArray:{doc:2}}}
3. {doc:{_id:2, lookupArray:[/* empty */]}}

So when you want to perform a search for a value doc from lookupArray, `$match` will look like this:

```
   {$match:{'lookupArray.doc':2}}
```

Any comments welcome!

Comment: What if I want to perform the `$lookup` and I also want to filter by a condition? So that way I'd get only 1 (or 0) results on the newly created field. Or said with other words, if I end up with multiple objects in the new field, is there a way I can filter that field and leave just the object with `doc: 2`?

Comment: you can use `$project` to manipulate document shape - if this helped you please mark as answer :-)

Comment: Don't worry, I'll mark your answer. Can you explain a little bit further about how I'd do it with `$project`?

Comment: using `$project` and then `$filter` on new array -> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/